# How can I do a fuzzy match for column name for data frame in R, so I can select them together

Tags: r

Say I have a dataframe like this

```
`str(data)
 $ ZN                        : int  1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 ...
 $ X.AB.FFLOWS               : int  17 17 22 22 22 17 17 17 17 22 ...
 $ X.BA.FFLOWS               : int  17 17 22 22 22 17 17 17 17 22 ...
 $ AB_COSTAM                 : num  0.197 0.535 0.51 0.528 0.361 ...
 $ BA_COSTAM                 : num  0.197 0.535 0.51 0.528 0.361 ...
 $ AB_COSTMD                 : num  0.197 0.535 0.51 0.528 0.361 ...
 $ BA_COSTMD                 : num  0.197 0.535 0.51 0.528 0.361 ...
 $ AB_COSTPM                 : num  0.197 0.535 0.51 0.528 0.361 ...
 $ BA_COSTPM                 : num  0.197 0.535 0.51 0.528 0.361 ...
 $ AB_COSTNT                 : num  0.197 0.535 0.51 0.528 0.361 ...
 $ BA_COSTNT                 : num  0.197 0.535 0.51 0.528 0.361 ...`
```

I want to delete all the column with *_COST*, how can I do it together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
data_reduced <- data[,-grep("_COST",colnames(data),fixed=T)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
data[,!grep!(".*_COST.*", colnames(data))]
```

Comment: yes it was a mistake you better '!' with grepl and '-' with grep